# Bootstrap Collapse Issue While clicking on other link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make some Bootstrap Toggle links to open by clicking on link and collapse by clicking again on that link.. It opening and closing well..I have 3 links to open and collapse.. If I click on Link1 , the toggle is opening and next I click on Link2 , that toggle also opening without closing the 1st link related toggle.. I know that I am missing some function.. but cant find the exact solution any where.. Here I have given the source code...

```
<div class="bd-example" data-example-id="">
  <p>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
      Button 1
    </button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
      Button 2
    </button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample3" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
      Button 3
    </button>
  </p>
<div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
  <div class="card card-block">
Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident.
  </div>
</div>
<div class="collapse" id="collapseExample2">
  <div class="card card-block">
    Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident 2.
  </div>
</div>
<div class="collapse" id="collapseExample3">
  <div class="card card-block">
    Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident 3.
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/ the second example shows you how to control multiple targets, not sure what version of bootstrap you are using?

Comment: @sore-spot the same link code I have used here..

Comment: Not quite you have used one button for one toggle using the id, in the example the 3rd button uses the class to target them both. It looks like you are wanting an accordion, check the 3rd example on that page.

Comment: @sore-spot --- checked the 3rd example, the same it was not closing by clicking the 2nd link... both links are opening.. I am trying to do is, ones I click on 2nd link the 1st link have to close..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="bd-example" data-example-id="" id="accordion">
<p>
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
Button 1
</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
Button 2
</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample3" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
Button 3
</button>
</p>
<div class="collapse" id="collapseExample" data-parent="#accordion">
<div class="card card-block">
Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident.
</div>
</div>
<div class="collapse" id="collapseExample2" data-parent="#accordion">
<div class="card card-block">
Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident 2.
</div>
</div>
<div class="collapse" id="collapseExample3" data-parent="#accordion">
<div class="card card-block">
Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident 3.
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Here you go buddy, you just needed to add data-parent attribute and use accordion functionality

Answer (score 0):

**You can use this method**

```
  <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
<div class="panel">
  <div role="tab" id="headingTwo" class="text-center">
    <button class="collapsed btn btn-primary" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne"
      aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
      Button 1
    </button>
    <button class="collapsed btn btn-primary" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo"
      aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
      Button 2
    </button>
    <button class="collapsed btn btn-primary" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree"
      aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
      Button 3
    </button>
  </div>
  <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse text-center collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
    <div class="panel-body">
      text .....
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse text-center collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
    <div class="panel-body">
      text .....
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse text-center collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree">
    <div class="panel-body">
      text .....
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```